# How to copy directory recursively from package to current path with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example，there is a boilerplate directory in my Python project's package, when run this CLI tool, I want to copy the boilerplate to current working path, How to make it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If `boilerplate` is not a Python package (a directory without `__init__.py` file), I recommend this way:

```
import os.path
import pkg_resources
import shutil

root_dir= os.path.dirname(pkg_resources.resource_filename('my_lib', '__init__.py'))
src_path = os.path.join(root_dir, "boilerplate")
if os.path.isdir(dst_path):
    shutil.rmtree(dst_path)
shutil.copytree(src_path, dst_path)
```

The idea:

- Get the root path of your library ("my_lib").
- Get the full path of the "boilerplate" in this *root_dir*.
- Then use `copytree` (unless you want to exclude some files, like ".svn").

Your library must be packaged with `zip_safe=False` (in the `setup.py`).